# Applying pre-trained BERT model to make predictions

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, bert-language-model

I have recently been given a BERT model that has been pre-trained with a mental health dataset that I have. Now all I have to do is apply the model to a larger dataset to test its performance. I am absolutely new to machine learning and am stuck in this step. I am using PyTorch and would like to continue using it. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/X/Downloads/number_users_09_05.csv',  encoding='unicode- 
    escape')
    
    REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE = re.compile('[/(){}\[\]\|@,;*]')
    BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')
    STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    
    # function to clean text
    def clean_text(text):
        text = text.lower() 
        text = REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE.sub(' ', text) 
        text = BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub(' ', text) 
        text = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if word not in STOPWORDS) 
        return text
    
    df['cleaned_text'] = df['post'].apply(clean_text)
    
    One-Hot Encoding
    
    df['Categories'] = df['Categories'].astype(str)
    
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
    df['Categories'] = df['Categories'].str.split(",").tolist()
    multilabel_binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    y = multilabel_binarizer.fit_transform(df['Categories'])
    print(multilabel_binarizer.classes_)
    
    for idx, Categories in enumerate(multilabel_binarizer.classes_):
        df[Categories] = y[:,idx]
    X = df['cleaned_text'].values
    
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    x_tr,x_val,y_tr,y_val=train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0,shuffle=True)
    
    input_dir = 'C:/Users/X/Documents/ppd_bert_model/'
    
    from transformers import AutoModelForMaskedLM
    model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(input_dir)
    
    from transformers import AutoTokenizer
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(input_dir)
    
    model.load_weights('C:/Users/X/Documents/ppd_bert_model/')
```

### At this step I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [30], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.load_weights('C:/Users/X/Documents/ppd_bert_model/')
      2 pred_prob = model.predict(x_val_seq)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1207, in Module.__getattr__(self, name)
   1205     if name in modules:
   1206         return modules[name]
-> 1207 raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
   1208     type(self).__name__, name))

AttributeError: 'BertForMaskedLM' object has no attribute 'load_weights'
```

Then after this I tried:

```
    pred_prob = model.predict(df['cleaned_text'])
```

### And got this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [28], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 pred_prob = model.predict(df['cleaned_text'])

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1207, in Module.__getattr__(self, name)
   1205     if name in modules:
   1206         return modules[name]
-> 1207 raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
   1208     type(self).__name__, name))

AttributeError: 'BertForMaskedLM' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

I have the pretrained model saved in a folder at 'C:/Users/X/Documents/ppd_bert_model/', and the model has three files: config.json, pytorch_model.bin, and vocab.txt. If anyone has any advice on how I should be calling and using the model to make predictions and test performance, please do let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can try to make your own predict function :D
if you are not familiar with that stuff take a look at PyTorch lightning

Comment: The error your getting has nothing to do with HuggingFace or BERT. If you look at the `BertForMaskedLM` code you'll notice that the object has no `predict` method. What you'll have to do is add a linear layer and use that as a classifier to make predictions.

Answer (score 1):

From the HuggingFace documentation [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/auto?highlight=automodelformaskedlm#transformers.AutoModelForMaskedLM), the `AutoModelForMaskedLM` class uses the `from_pretrained()` method to instantiate one of the model classes of the library (with a masked language modeling head) from a pretrained model. This is done either by using the `model_type` property in the config object (either passed as an argument, or loaded from `pretained_model_name_or_path` (in your case "C:/Users/X/Documents/ppd_bert_model/"), or if the `model_type` property is missing, it will fall back to pattern matching on `pretrained_model_name_or_path`.

Based on your first error `AttributeError: 'BertForMaskedLM' object has no attribute 'load_weights'`, the [BertForMaskedLM](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.23.1/en/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertForMaskedLM) is being automatically loaded and an associated class instantiated by the `from_pretrained()` method call. If you follow the documentation I've hyperlinked, and look at the `BertForMaskedLM` class, there is no method `load_weights()`, hence the first error you encountered with your method call. You'll also see in the documentation that there is no `predict()` method, hence the second error you encountered. At the bottom of that subsection you'll find an example code snippet that shows you how to use the `BertForMaskedLM` model for masked token prediction. I'll reproduce the snippet here for your convenience and future reference, should their documentation change or the link break:

```
>>> from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM
>>> import torch

>>> tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
>>> model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

>>> inputs = tokenizer("The capital of France is [MASK].", return_tensors="pt")

>>> with torch.no_grad():
...    logits = model(**inputs).logits

>>> # retrieve index of [MASK]
>>> mask_token_index = (inputs.input_ids == tokenizer.mask_token_id)[0].nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]

>>> predicted_token_id = logits[0, mask_token_index].argmax(axis=-1)

>>> tokenizer.decode(predicted_token_id)
'paris'
```

Hopefully this helps get you on the right track towards making predictions and testing performance.